# R Graphs: Decreasing extra space between main title and graph

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to remove space between the title of my histogram and where the y axis begins. I have edited top, bottom, and side margins, but the space between title and y axis has remained the same. Any suggestions? Here is my code...

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar = c(4, 4, 4, 1) + 0.1, oma = c(1, 1, 3, 1))

hist(data$variable1, xlim = c(1,5), 
     main="Title here",  breaks=seq(1,5,1), 
     freq=TRUE, xlab=" ", ylim = c(0,18), 
     border="white", col="gray", cex.main = 2)

hist(data$variable2, xlim = c(1,5), 
     main="Title here", breaks=seq(1,5,1), 
     freq=TRUE, xlab=" ", ylim = c(0,18), 
     border="white", col="gray", cex.main = 2)

hist(data$variable3, xlim = c(1,5), 
     main="Title here", breaks=seq(1,5,1), 
     freq=TRUE, xlab=" ", ylim = c(0,18), 
     border="white", col="gray", cex.main = 2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One might wish that `line.main` would work as an argument to `hist` (analogous to `cex.main` and similar), but unfortunately that does not appear to be implemented.  You *can* pass `line=0` to `hist`, but it will affect x- and y-axis titles (and the subtitle, if there is one), not just the main title. To adjust only the main title, plot it separately:

```
hist(rnorm(50), main=NA)
title("A close-set title", line=0)
```